# Parsing JSON dict results in TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, json

I have `json` stored in a `dict` called `rasa_decoded_output` which returns the following json:

```
{
  "entities": [

  ],
  "intent_ranking": [
    {
      "confidence": 0.712699869084774,
      "name": "st_testing"
    },
    {
      "confidence": 0.033084814164303,
      "name": "emergency"
    },
    {
      "confidence": 0.024547592443969,
      "name": "exists_item"
    },
    {
      "confidence": 0.023160524284639,
      "name": "check_out"
    },
    {
      "confidence": 0.022475491594176,
      "name": "broken_climate"
    },
    {
      "confidence": 0.021986762111397,
      "name": "exisits_hours_fitness_center"
    },
    {
      "confidence": 0.019758362302795,
      "name": "st_compliment"
    },
    {
      "confidence": 0.019739803875883,
      "name": "request_profane"
    },
    {
      "confidence": 0.01857200162444,
      "name": "broken_catchall"
    },
    {
      "confidence": 0.016882101663941,
      "name": "exists_vending"
    }
  ],
  "intent": {
    "confidence": 0.072699869084774,
    "name": "st_testing"
  },
  "text": "Testing this stuff"
}
```

I'm trying to to extract the first occurrence of `confidence` and `name`, which I'm doing through the following code:

```
intent_rank1 = rasa_decoded_output['intent_ranking']['name']
confidence_rank1 = rasa_decoded_output['intent_ranking']['confidence']
```

However, this is resulting in the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`. What is the proper way to store a value from the json into an object. I'm not sure where my misstep is. I suspect it is related to not specifying which occurrence of name or confidence in my code.

My understanding is that in this case there is no issue with it being a `dict`. Using `json.dumps()` and looking into it with the same code results in `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

Comment: `intent_rank1 = rasa_decoded_output['intent_ranking'][0]['name']`

Comment: And, `confidence_rank1 = rasa_decoded_output['intent_ranking'][0]['confidence']` The `intent_ranking` is a list.

Comment: Added an answer with a little extra info, for posterity. Do accept if you feel like it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intent_ranking` is not a dictionary, but a list of dictionaries. You'll need something along the lines of

```
intent_rank_i = rasa_decoded_output['intent_ranking'][i]['name']
```

Or,

```
confidence_rank_i = rasa_decoded_output['intent_ranking'][i]['confidence']
```

Where `i` refers to the `ith` element in the list.

To iterate over each value, you can use a loop:

```
for d in rasa_decoded_output['intent_ranking']:
    i = d['name']
    c = d['confidence'] 
    ... # something else
```

Answer (score 0):

The following won't work because `rasa_decoded_output['intent_ranking']` is a `list` (Array equivalent in other languages like Java / C++ / Javascript) of `dict`s.

```
intent_rank1 = rasa_decoded_output['intent_ranking']['name']
```

**Solution**

1. If you are sure that `confidence` and `ranking` are going to come in the first item in the list then use this -

   ```
   intent_rank1 = rasa_decoded_output['intent_ranking'][0]['name']
   confidence_rank1 = rasa_decoded_output['intent_ranking'][0]['confidence']
   ```
2. Otherwise, you could use the following

   ```
   data = {
       "entities": [...],
       "intent_ranking": [...]
   }    

   def get_first_intent_and_confidence(data):
       for info in data.get('intent_ranking', []):
           if 'name' in info and 'confidence' in info:
               return info['name'], info['confidence']

   intent, confidence = get_first_intent_and_confidence(data)
   ```

Comment: Yeah, noticed that. Posted a fix.